# Weird MySQL Model synchronization error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[image]

Why do I get this weird error when trying to synchronise my model with the mysql database (v5.7.19, workbench v6.3.9)? As you can see from the screenshot, `table1_createdOn` doesn't even have a default value, and if i run the generated command with sql query it works:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`table1` (
  `createdOn` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`createdOn`))

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`table2` (
  `createdAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `table1_createdOn` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`table1_createdOn`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_round_table1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`table1_createdOn`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`table1` (`createdOn`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Comment: FYI - if possible, please don't use screenshots where you can paste in actual text (which does look to be the case here). It's easier to update when needed, easier to read, and easier to work with.

Comment: What was in the "logs"?

Comment: the "Message Log" in the screenshot is the logs. Are you able to replicate the bug by creating 2 tables with a TIMESTAMP attribute and linking them via the 1:n relationship, as seen in the screenshot? (Or run the SQL query then reverse engineer to get the ER model).

Comment: Don't post the same question on [different SO  sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46740076/weird-mysql-model-synchronization-error), just to get more attentation!